# Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript

I can't find the problem in my code could someone please help on this issue?
Here's my source code

```
<button onclick="myfunction()" class="button" id="btw1" > Voir numéro   </button>

<script type=text/javascript> 
            function myfunction(){
           
            var bouton= document.getElementById('btw1');
           
             var parent= document.body;

            var nvbtw = document.createElement('btw2');
            nvbtw.id='btw2';
            nvbtw.innerHTML='<button  class="button" id="btw2" > (+33 00 00 00 00 00)   </button>';
            
            parent.replaceChild(nvbtw,bouton);
}</script>
```

What I want to do is a hidden button number like when you click on it it shows the number.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that `bouton` is not a *direct* child of `document.body`. Instead of `var parent = document.body`, use:

```
var parent = bouton.parentElement; // or `.parentNode`
```

---

Side note: If you're targeting modern browsers, you may find [`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) easier to work with:

```
bouton.replaceWith(nvbtw);
```

*(It can also be polyfilled for older browsers.)*